# Why is the Vatican (Rome) the center of Christianity?

Tags: christianity

Jesus Christ was born and died in Palestine. Why did Christianity move to Vatican (Rome) and became the center of Christianity?

Comment: This should get you started : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Christianity

Comment: I'm pretty sure a few moments researching church history would answer this question adequately.

Comment: Apostle Peter established himself in Rome. Later after his death the church or Rome declared that they were the supreme church among others because Jesus declared about Peter the following "On this rock I will build my church". Also that is why the Pope is the successor of Peter.

Comment: You might be able to ask this on [Christianity StackExchange](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The Vatican is not the center of Christianity.  I suppose that there could be many millions of non Catholic Christians who might be upset by your assumption.   The Vatican is merely the center of the largest sect, cult,  denomination, or group of any kind, of Christians.  Because the Vatican in Rome is the center of the largest and most centralized group of Christians, Roman Catholics, it is by far the most significant center of Christian clerical organization.  Thus it is easy to assume it is the center of Chrisitanity.

Comment: PS - Over the ages a lot of disgruntled Catholics asked the same question as Rell Bunag, and lacking answers they considered satisfactory, started movements the Catholic hierarchy considered schismatic or heretical, thus creating many of the competing Christian denominations.  So Rell Bunag's question is an over simplified version of the ones asked by the founders of many present denominations with millions of followers.

Comment: On christianity stack exchange: [Why is Rome the holy city?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15843/why-is-rome-the-holy-city).

Comment: The Vatican has been and is still the Capital and Central location for Roman Catholic Christianity, but NOT for the entire worldwide Christian population, There are an estimated 2 billion Christians worldwide, whereby 1.2 billion-(or 60% of the world's Christian population), are self-identified and practicing Roman Catholics.  The Pope is the Heir to Saint Peter-(who, according, to Roman Catholics), was the First Pope in History.  However, there are 800 million Christians worldwide-(approximately 40% of the world's Christian population who are NOT Roman Catholic).

Comment: Although the Vatican has been and is still, a very, very powerful global institution, it is has NOT and does NOT represent the entirety of Christendom.  There are 300 million Eastern rite-(mostly "Orthodox") Christians worldwide and approximately 500 million Protestant or Protestant related Christian communities worldwide.  There is no  Center for Protestantism and although there is Constantinople/(present-day Istanbul) for the Orthodox Christians, there are still numerous quasi-autonomously administered Orthodox Churches throughout the Balkans, Egypt, Russia and Ethiopia.

Comment: Neither Protestantism, nor Eastern rite/(more specifically, Orthodox Christianity), are ruled by the Vatican and therefore, such historically and contemporaneously independent Ecclesiastical Institutions have their respective Leaderships elsewhere in the world........and NOT in the Vatican. Therefore, to say that the Vatican is the "Center" of Christianity, is intellectually and historically erroneous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Christianity got established in both capitals of the Roman Empire.
2. The two parts of the Roman Empire split.
3. The people around the capital of the Eastern Empire became [Orthodox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthodoxy), those around the capital of the Western Empire became what would be called [Catholic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catholic_Church) later on.
4. Constantinople "[fell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_Constantinople)". That left Rome.

Comment: If Vatican is capital of Catholics, then what is capital of mainstream Christians? Is there any other Capital for other sects in Christianity as well? Curious to know

Comment: @TalhaIrfan The tldr version is that there are 15 "capitals" for the Orthodox Church, a few more for the Oriental churches, One for the Coptics, and many hundreds for the various protestant and pentecostal groups

Comment: +1 for the brilliant (if simplistic) summary.

Comment: You have got point 4 reversed by a 1,000 year error.

Comment: @TalhaIrfan what on earth is a "mainstream" Christian?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Barbarians like Alaric and Odoacer were Christians. Should be "4. Constantinople fell to non-Christians (to Muslims). Rome had a downfall too, but remained in Christian hands; so they were able to rebuild it."

Comment: @TalhaIrfan Catholic and Orthodox church were the "mainstream"

Comment: @Some_Guy I never differentiated among the two until this year when I talked with someone on internet about Catholic Church and the reply I got was "Hey dude! Listen, we are Christians, not Catholic. Catholics are like Shias in Islam." And I have heard more or less similar statement from couple of other "mainstream Christians"

Comment: @Greg, some Catholics would deny that Orthodox are mainstream, and vice versa.

Comment: @Talha Irfan: For Anglicans, the capital would perhaps be Canterbury/London, since the Archbishop of Canterbury is the head of the Anglican Church.  AFAIK, most of the other western Protestant sects don't seem to have that much in the way of a centralized hierarchy - though I admit I'm no expert.

Comment: @TalhaIrfan OK, so you don't seem to know that much about Christianity at all. There is no "mainstream Christianity". It sounds like you were talking to maybe an American evangelical? Within their community they would be the mainstream, but globally they are a minority. Main denominations of Christianity and when they split of, and numbers of followers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_denomination#Taxonomy , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Christian_denominations_by_number_of_members. The history of Christianity and Islam are very different, analogies don't really work well.

Comment: @TalhaIrfan Your knowledge is so low on this that you might want to read through the basics of Christian denominations and Schisms.  The main groups are Catholic, Orthodox, Protestant (usually including Anglicanism, sometimes seen as separate) Orthodox and Catholic split 1000 years ago, Catholic and Protestant 500 years ago.  There are A MILLION DIFFERENT TYPES of protestant Christianities, some with millions of members, some with just 100, Some have a central organisation, some are just loosely affiliated. Catholic and Orthodox Churches have a strict organisation & hierachy.

Comment: @Some A fourth should be "other" as there are self-identified Christians that would not identify as any of those three groups.

Comment: @fredsbend true but as I said, just giving the main groups. There are plenty of other smaller groups, ancient and modern; Assyrian Christians to Jehova's witnesses

Comment: @jamesqf  The highest title in Church of England is the Supreme Governor, which is the British monarch

Comment: This answer should probably also mention the Office of Peter as Head of the Church, who is traditionally held to the first Bishop of Rome, eventually being martyrded there. The Office of Peter, the Pope, stayed as Bishop of Rome, continuing through today.

Comment: @JamesHaug, my answer posits that the theological justification followed the political influence, not the other way around.

Comment: @o.m. Then your answer is only half-correct. If Catholics/early-church didn't believe in the Office of Peter as Head of the Church, then the Church would've functioned more like the Orthodox Patriarchs, meaning that as Rome lost political influence with the fall of the west, it would also lose the religious influence, and there would have been no argument against Constantinople as the primary see of the Church. That did not happen (with the notable exception of the schism of East and West), obviously, as Rome still stands as the primary See for Catholicism.